# Building a Webapp - Should I use pure Angular 2 or go with Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm going to build a webapp that will be used on multiple devices from desktops to pads and phones.

This is going to be a responsive (of course) webapp, but now my question is if I have anything to gain using Ionic 2 on top of Angular 2, "just in case" there's a need for a compiled mobile app later (not at all likely atm).

Is the use case for Ionic only if I intend at some time build a mobile app?

Will adding Ionic 2 just increase the complexity since I only have the need for a Webapp? Is there some other thing to gain on using Ionic 2 instead of pure Angular 2?

I tried googling around and searching here on SO, but since both are quite new, there isn't that much info out there yet.

I've already fiddled around a bit with Ionic2 to try to get a feel for what it is, but I haven't yet aquired the knowledge on what parts are Ionic and what are Angular since that project was more of a mobile app.
Can anyone help with the understanding when to choose which?

I'm aiming on TypeScript

It's kind of hard to not venture into the "opinion-based" part with this question, but what I'm after is a sort of comparison chart with what's added with Ionic, that I don't get from native Ng2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One drawback of using ionic 2 instead of plain angular 2 is that ionic currently does not supports the angular's explicit URL routing out of the box, but uses stacked navigation (URL won't change when you change page). That is somehow acceptable for mobile app, but not that great for an browser which has a address bar.  [Here is discussion on state of the art and future of routing in ionic 2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-urls-to-navigate-in-ionic-2/38233/10?u=peter1655).

Another reason to consider when picking Ionic 2 for your project is that select&copy text will not work by default (because Ionic is focused on touchscreens). Yes, you can resolve that but be prepared that it takes more than just few css changes ([at least in ionic 1 it was not as easy as I thought](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-make-text-selectable/4384/2)).

Also not sure if you are about to write your app in typescript or JS, but ionic 2 seem to focus more on JS (e.g. the way how examples are written), while angular seems to pay more attention to typescript. Again not a blocker whaterver is your choice (js or typescript), but you will probably waste some time trying to convert code samples from one language into the other or vice versa..

Comment: Thanks, it was an answer in this style I was looking for, some hands-on fact based answer.
Just to add AFAIK Ionic 2 is built with TypeScript, I think the reason there's a lot of js only examples is that that was the default generated when they started, this is now changed to generate TS files as default.